# Scale image to the same size as the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have an orthographic camera which scales based on device.

I have a background image (sprite renderer) which the default is 960 x 560;

My game is in landscape mode btw.

Im trying to fill the cameras background with this image but I cant seem to scale it correctly. I have tried the following script on the background image:

```
public Camera camera;

void Start()
{
    float camHeight = camera.pixelHeight;
    float camWidth = camera.pixelWidth;

    float scaledWidth = camWidth / 960;
    float scaledHeight = camHeight / 560;

    Vector3 scale = new Vector3(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, transform.localScale.z);
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
```

Which scales it ok for phone but insanly big for ipad. Then i try:

```
public Camera camera;

void Start()
{
    float pixelRatio = (camera.orthographicSize * 2) / camera.pixelHeight;

    float scaledWidth = pixelRatio * 960;
    float scaledHeight = pixelRatio * 560;

    Vector3 scale = new Vector3(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, transform.localScale.z);
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
```

Which just stretches it out very long. Anyone know how i can get a perfect fit? or near perfect

Comment: What type of component? UI Image? UI RawImage? SpriteRenderer?

Comment: It is a sprite renderer

Comment: Why don't you use a Skybox component as background? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues in the end i just ended up making a ui image and stretched it full screen and made it render in the camera space

Comment: UI Image or RawImage are the proper way to do that these days. It's complicated to do these with SpriteRenderer